# Which image effect is this?

Tags: unity, image-effects

This is a screenshot from RE7.
I have once seen the same image effect in Unity, but I don't remember the name:

[image]

I'm not talking about AA or DOF here, I mean this grainy / greenish thing, I don't know how to describe it...

At first I thought the name was something like "Anisotrophic filtering", but that didn't bring up anything that looked like it.

Can anybody tell me the name of the effect that I see here?

Edit:
It can be seen in the start screen of this video, too:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/aaN3MNb9ij0?feature=oembed

Both screenshots look pretty similar to me, so I guess it's the same effect?

Edit 2:

The pixels seem to shift into red / blue the closer they get to the edge of the screens.

I have drawn red arrows to region where this effect is very visible to me.
These pixels appear as "shifted" to me.

I think this effect is more visible at the edge of the screen.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything greenish there. You'd better highlight the area you are talking about so we have at least some idea what you're talking about...

Comment: I also don't see anything that looks "grainy" or "greenish"

Comment: I'll post an answer with some suggestions in a minute, but a question - are you red-green colorblind?

Comment: @Kevin I don't think so. The 2 images do look different to me, but still they share something, I think. I just can't say what it is.

Comment: If you're seeing green, that could mean your monitor color isn't calibrated correctly (a common problem; I use a professional color calibrator to make sure mine is accurate). I don't see anything I would call "grain" and am not sure what you are referring to. It might help if you drew a circle around the portion of the screenshot you're referring to. Anyway, I'm writing up an answer regarding the effects I see in the video.

Comment: @Kevin Both images have a greenish tint all over them for me. I have 2 monitors, on both I see this greenish tint.

Comment: These examples are not very effective in isolating the effect you want to ask about. I'm not sure whether you're describing chromatic aberration, spherical aberration, film grain, colour grading, ambient occlusion, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you are referring to, as I don't see any effect that looks grainy or greenish in the screenshots or clips (other than a few green objects on the desk, but I'm sure that's not what you're referring to).

As far as effects I see:

From the RE7 screenshot

- The only obvious visual effect in the RE screenshot (aside from DOF) is a blood smear in the top-left corner of the image (which is red and not grainy).

From the Unity HQ Abandoned School video:

- [Bloom](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Bloom.html) - Creates a glow around bright parts of the image; can also be combined with a lens dirt texture to create the look of a dirty lens. Bloom is visible around the sun/sky in the external shots, and I think there's lens dirt in the shot of the desk with lamp, though they are also using a particle effect to simulate dust in the air. There's also some mild lens dirt or lens flare in a few other shots
- [Chromatic aberration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Chromatic-Aberration.html): A few shots might have very mild chromatic aberration. It's hard to describe this effect and I suggest doing an image search for it.
- [Color grading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Color-Grading.html): Adjusts the color tone of the image, such as saturation, tint, and contrast. Some shots look like they might use color grading to achieve a more stylized look (e.g. adding a little sepia, reducing black levels).
- [Vignette](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Vignette.html): darkens the edges of the image. I believe this effect is applied uniformly on every shot.

Regarding the green, these are the parts of the desk image that Photoshop thinks have some green (determined by increasing the saturation "Greens" in the Hue/Saturation window by 100).
[image]

Here's the image with the same range of green completely desaturated. On my calibrated monitor the difference from the original image is barely noticeable. If it still looks very green to you, that suggests to me that your monitor isn't calibrated correctly.

[image]

As for the RE7 image, if I put it into Photoshop and raise the saturation of "greens" by 100, the image doesn't change at all; in other words, in contains no green at all.

EDIT: Here's an example of Chromatic Aberration
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I mean something else. The closer the objects are to the edge of the screen, the more "shifted" their pixels appear. I will add this to my question.

Comment: @tmighty That's probably chromatic aberration.

Comment: @tmighty I've added an example of chromatic aberration

Comment: Thank you, I could reproduce the red / green shift with Chromatic Aberration. I'm using URP, and it doesn't look like any of the 2 screenshots, but I least I get this shift that I observed.

Comment: @tmighty Glad you're on the right track. If this answer was helpful, please don't forget to upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll share my opinion with you. I am not sure where you are pointing exactly but from the comments and your post I feel like slight **hue rotation** effect could give you this kind of results.
[image]